# Solve Linear Least Squares Problem with Unit Simplex Constraint

Tags: least-squares, quadratic-programming

$$
\min_x ||Ax - b||_2\; \;\text{given }x \geq 0\;\;\text{and}\;\;\textbf{1}^Tx = 1 
$$
I am trying to do the above optimization, I was using common Quadratic programming libraries but their speed is too less. I believe this problem needs much less general optimization routine. I was able to find non-negative least squares optimizations but they didn't offer any linear constrains. I read in few articles online that the dimensionality of the problem can be reduces by considering $x_n = 1-  \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1}x_i$, and can be optimized using non-negative least squares optimization (shouldn't we in such cases constrain $\sum x_i$ to be less than 1 ?)

Thanks :)

Edit: I am really sorry, I have changed the > to >= condition.

Comment: How large is $A$?

Comment: There are some iterative algorithms using gradient descent and projection on the affine subspace of the solution.

Comment: A is not so large, somewhere around 1500x500.

Comment: I added code with very fast and efficient methods (MATLAB). For you dimensions it takes  0.07 [Sec] with the Frank Wolfe method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is given by:

$$
\begin{alignat*}{3}
\arg \min_{x} & \quad & \frac{1}{2} \left\| A x - b \right\|_{2}^{2} \\
\text{subject to} & \quad & x \succeq 0 \\
& \quad & \boldsymbol{1}^{T} x = 1
\end{alignat*}
$$

Which I solved in my answer to [How to Project onto the Unit Simplex as Intersection of Two Sets (Optimizing a Convex Function)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2404265)?

I tried to write code in order to extend what I did there.
So I wrote a MATLAB Code which is accessible in my [StackExchange Mathematics Q2935650 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes/tree/master/Mathematics/Q2935650).

The solvers I implemented / used are as following:

1. [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx/) as a reference.
2. Projected Gradient Descent with Projection onto the Unit Simplex as I implemented in [Orthogonal Projection onto the Unit Simplex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2402504).
3. Projected Gradient Descent with Projection onto the Unit Simplex implemented as Alternating Projections for the projection of the intersection of 2 convex sets. See [Projections onto Convex Sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projections_onto_convex_sets) and [How to Project onto the Unit Simplex as Intersection of Two Sets (Optimizing a Convex Function)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2404265).
4. Conditional Gradient Method ([Frank Wolfe Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank%E2%80%93Wolfe_algorithm)).

The results are given by:

[image]

Timing for handling your case of $ A \in \mathbb{R}^{1500 \times 500} $ is less than a second in either of the methods I implemented.

The Frank Wolfe method is simple for this case. Indeed the Set is compact hence convergence is guaranteed. Since the convex hull of the Unit Simplex is given by Standard Basis the optimization is simple:

$$ \arg \min_{s \in \Delta} \nabla f \left( x \right)^{T} s = \arg \min_{i} {\left( \nabla f \left( x \right) \right)}_{i} $$

Where $ f \left( x \right) = \frac{1}{2} {\left\| A x - b \right\|}_{2}^{2} $ and $ \Delta = \left\{ x \mid \boldsymbol{1}^{T} x = 1, \, x \succeq 0 \right\} $ is the Unit Simplex Set.
So the solution is basically the element of the gradient with the minimal value.

This method becomes really simple and very fast for your case.

All methods could be even faster by:

- Implement acceleration for the Gradient based methods (Have a look on what I did on [How to Solve Linear Least Squares Problem with Box Constraints](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3558240)).
- Adaptive Step Size for Frank Wolfe method (Line search should work nicely).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is known as a standard quadratic program ([StQP](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs10107-012-0519-x.pdf), see pg. 3 for details). If you relax the constraint on the sum of the entries to a sum of the absolute value of the entries, and the strict inequality to non-strict, one can show by duality that this problem has an $\ell_{1}$ minimization interpretation which is quickly solved for. The un-relaxed problem is a bit more complex to solve.

Generally the solution to the problems have a lot of zero entries when $x>0$ is replaced with $x\geq 0$ so the relaxation may not have the properties you want.

Comment: Could you show the dual is a simple $ {L}_{1} $ problem? I am pretty sure it won't have closed form solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is very large then a proximal algorithm such as FISTA could be a good choice. You can formulate the problem as minimizing $f(x) + g(x)$ where 
$$
f(x) = \frac12 \|Ax-b\|_2^2
$$
and $g$ is the convex indicator function of the probability simplex. This is the correct problem form for the proximal gradient method and for accelerated proximal gradient methods such as FISTA. You will need to be able to compute the gradient of $f$ and the prox-operator of $g$. The gradient of $f$ is 
$$
\nabla f(x) = A^T (Ax-b).
$$
The proximal operator of $g$ performs a projection onto the probability simplex. Methods for performing this projection efficiently can be found by googling.

You can learn more about proximal algorithms from Boyd's booklet called Proximal Algorithms (among other resources).

Comment: A is my case is not really large, its somewhere aroung 1500x500. But I have 20,000 such problems.

Comment: @Aditya In that case, since the problem is not very large, a classical interior point method might be a good way to go. Which quadratic programming library did you use? The library can make a big difference.

Comment: [ALGLIB](http://www.alglib.net/) . I am using the free version of it. They provide 3 algos to optimize quadratic problems. I use QP-BLEIC solver.

Comment: @Aditya How long does it take to solve the optimization problem? Also, how fast do you need it to be? It is possible that the problem could be solved much faster by using an interior point method -- for example, you could formulate the problem as a second-order cone program and solve it using the MOSEK software package. I think that would be a very standard approach for a medium-sized problem like this one.

Comment: It takes like half a minute or sometimes more to solve a problem. Thanks I will into MOSEK.